# Where can I find example circuits to learn from?

Tags: computational-models, machine-learning

I'm relatively new to quantum computing and my goal is to learn how to implement algorithms that I read in papers. While I have found many circuit snippets I have yet to find a repository of examples on GitHub or other places where I would go to find machine learning code.  Does an analogous quantum computing repository exist?

Comment: I'm confused. What do you want to code ? Machine learning algorithms or quantum algorithms?

Comment: I"m interested in quantum algorithms relevant to machine learning, anything from inverting a matrix (which there are very small examples of) to things like KNN, SVM etc performed on quantum computers.  Some QASM or circuit diagrams would be quite helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know this is not what you are asking but this paper: 
[Quantum Algorithm Implementations for Beginners](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.03719) explains the implementation of some machine learning algorithms. Hope this helps!

Comment: This article is a goldmine for learning.  Thank you!